# Dockerfile `RUN --mount=type=ssh` does'nt work with ssh repository dependancies inside package.json / package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, docker, package-lock.json, docker-buildkit, docker-secrets

I tried to build a nodejs application with ssh external dependancies with and without package-lock.json in a Dockerfile.

It seems that --mount=type=ssh doesn't works recursively when cloning external ssh dependancies with npm

package-lock.json contains :
`"version": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#4db813c75b98977b10886ceeb761f5f0fcf92f40", "from": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#v4.0.0-pre.7",`

It seems that if I remove the package-lock.json it will work but it doesn't work if it is present, I don't know why.

I don't understand why the secret or mount option is not recursively used within the npm "subprocess" retrieve command.

Though Fixing the versions with the package-lock.json should be built-in.

This is a snake that bites its own tail case.

> Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfcd85

In the Dockerfile :

`RUN --mount=type=ssh /usr/local/bin/npm install --loglevel silly`

Run with option :

--ssh default=$HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519

In the package.json :

`"dependance": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#v4.0.0-pre.7"`

In the package-lock.json :

`"version": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#4db813c75b98977b10886ceeb761f5f0fcf92f40", "from": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#v4.0.0-pre.7",`

--mount=type=ssh doesn't clone the dependance because it can't see the private key authorization

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the url syntax is wrong:

##### Wrong:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx:common/dependance.git#v4.0.0-pre.7
```

##### Correct:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.xxxx.xxx/common/dependance.git#v4.0.0-pre.7
```

Comment: It would be helpful for future readers if you were to point out the precise difference between the two entries (the colon).